# How to assign ItemsSource to ComboBox in ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, listbox, datatemplate

Here are my current codes, simplified to the relevant:

```
<telerik:RadListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0, 5, 5, 5"
            x:Name="listBoxIssue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Height="690" Width="793"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lbIssueTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="lbIssueTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0" Width="Auto">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>             
            <ComboBox x:Name="PrintCode" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      SelectedValuePath="PrintCode" DisplayMemberPath="PrintCode" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

So with this binding setup, there should be a value attached to the ComboBox's SelectedPath. Now I just need to bind a list of choices to the ComboBox. I accomplished this in GridView with the following code:

```
((GridViewComboBoxColumn)gridPrintOption.Columns["PrintCode"]).ItemsSource = listPrintCode;
```

I am hoping to achieve something like the code above in this scenario as well. The difficulty here is that I can't get the name of the Column nor can I use .Columns since these are DataTemplate.

Note: I'm not using MVVM.

Comment: see if there are any binding errors? also make sure that the the ItemsSource of RadListBox is a collection of collection.

Comment: @pushpraj There are no errors. Rather than there being a problem with the bindings, it's actually I don't know how to access the relevant controls to bind. Everything else is working fine - I have checkboxes, textboxes etc in the RadListBox. It's just that ComboBox is more complex as it needs 2 different bindings - the SelectedValuePath, and the ItemsSource. To reiterate again, I accomplished this in GridView, but not here as I have difficulties in accessing the needed controls.

Answer (score 1):

try this

> xaml

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="lbIssueTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0" Width="Auto">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ComboBox x:Name="PrintCode" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.PrintCode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Choices, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox Background="Red" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lbIssueTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Equips}"></ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

> xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

> Equip class I have used only PrintCode property

```
    public class Equip:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public Equip()
    {
        PrintCode = "All";
    }

    private string printcode;
    public string PrintCode
    {
        get { return printcode; }
        set { printcode = value; OnPropertychanged("PrintCode"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertychanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

> ViewModel

```
    public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Choices = new ObservableCollection<string> { "All", "Left", "Right", "None" };
        Equips = new ObservableCollection<Equip>() { new Equip(), new Equip() };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Equip> Equips { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Choices { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's not it. To help in understanding I shall give an example: let 'Equip' be the object binded to ListBox, whose properties are Name (ABC), Serial (123), Quantity (5), and PrintCode (All). These are binded easily. But for PrintCode, I want the ComboBox to be binded to give choices, which are "None", "Left", "Right" and "All". Upon binding, the SelectedValue will automatically be "All" (as per above Equip Object). Upon dropping down the ComboBox, it should have "None", "Left" etcs. For this to happen, it requires binding to another Object (PrintCode), not the ListBox's object (Equip).

Comment: Ok now i got whats the problem i have update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! As far as I understand what's going on, I can't afford to implement MVVM as mentioned. I can only experiment the next day as it's now after work-hours here, but currently I have a feeling that something is lacking if MVVM isn't implemented. 
That's why I'm most comfortable if the code is somewhere along the line like   
>GridViewComboBoxColumn)gridPrintOption.Columns["PrintCode"]).ItemsSource = listPrintCode  
This would be the case if the ComboBox is in a GridView, which is pretty straightforward.